# Finding the voltage of an inductor in a RL series circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits

[image]

Here is the solution:

[image]

This assigned question is an odd one since it doesn't seem to have anything to do with phasors which is the chapter I am currently studying. I know that that the phase relationship in a RL circuit is that voltage leads current but I'm not sure why they used Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Which book you are studying? If the chapter is really about phasors then the book had for sure explained RL series circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it doesn't seem to have anything to do with phasors

But it does since this is the way one [*adds* phasors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor#Addition).  Assume you have two series connected circuit elements with phasor voltages that differ in phase by the angle $\phi$.

$$\vec V_1 = V_1$$

$$\vec V_2 = V_2e^{j\phi}$$

Since the voltage across the series combination is the *sum* of the individual phasor voltages, the *magnitude* of the phasor voltage sum is given by:

$$|\vec V_{sum}| = \sqrt{V^2_1 + V^2_2 + 2V_1V_2\cos\phi}$$

In the case that $\phi = 90^\circ$, as for the series connected resistor and inductor, we have

$$|\vec V_{sum}| = \sqrt{V^2_1 + V^2_2 + 2V_1V_2\cos90^\circ}= \sqrt{V^2_1 + V^2_2} $$

---

> How do you know that they are 90 degrees out of phase?

The resistor and inductor are in series thus they have identical current

$$\vec I_R = \vec I_L =\vec I $$

The voltage across the resistor is

$$\vec V_R = R \vec I_R = R \vec I $$

and the voltage across the inductor is

$$\vec V_L = j\omega L \vec I_L =  j\omega L \vec I$$

We can express the voltage across the inductor in terms of the voltage across the resistor

$$\vec V_L = j\frac{\omega L}{R}\vec V_R = \frac{\omega L}{R}\vec V_R\, e^{j90^\circ}$$

Thus, see that the inductor voltage and resistor voltage are in *quadrature* - they differ in phase by $90^{\circ}$

Comment: How do you know that they are 90 degrees out of phase? Is it because it is a purely inductive circuit? I thought that purely inductive circuits can't resistors which means that RL circuits are not purely inductive?

Comment: @user43921, see the update to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$V_L$ and $V_R$ are [phasors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor) which are 90 degree out of phase. Like two vectors, phasors follow the same rule for addition that's why they have used pythagoras theorem.

Comment: I think what OP is asking is: why do they seem to use quadratic addition when the current chapter is not about phasors?

Comment: @Kvothe Sorry for confusion. The current chapter I am studying is about phasors. Thank you for the answers. It has helped my understanding.

Comment: How do you know that they are 90 degrees out of phase? Is it because it is a purely inductive circuit? I thought that purely inductive circuits can't resistors which means that RL circuits are not purely inductive?